# JQuel slider text box not following validation rules

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I made this little multiplication table maker. Right now almost everything works, it is meant to dynamically create a table based on the sliders within it, and allow for int input into the box for the sliders. My one issue right now is that my int input does not follow my validation function. It skips it and allows for a user to input an invalid value such as 54 (the table is meant to only run for numbers from -50 to 50). If anyone sees anything glaringly wrong with this, please help a young buck out.

EDIT: My issue is that the values the user can input to the input box are not valid under my val function, I could type in 54 and it will produce a multiplication table up to that. I would like it so that if 54 is entered an error message will come up and not create the new table

```js
function sub() {
  if ($("form[name='tabley-boy']").valid() == true) {
    $("form[name='tabley-boy']").submit();
  }
}

function slidez() {
  $("#slider_min_row").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mnrows").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("#mnrows").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_min_row").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });

  $("#slider_max_row").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mxrows").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("#mxrows").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_max_row").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });

  $("#slider_min_col").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mncols").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("mnrows").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_min_col").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });

  $("#slider_max_col").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mxcols").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("#mxcols").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_max_col").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });
}

function val() {
  $("form[name='tabley-boy']").validate({
    rules: {
      mnrows: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
        //le: '#mxrows'
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
      },
      mncols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
        //le: '#mxcols'
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
      }
    },
    messages: {
      mnrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
        //le: "Your minimum number for rows must be less than your maximum"
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
      },
      mncols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
        //le: "Your minimum number for columns must be less than your maximum"
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
      Table();
      return false;
    },
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
      sub();
    }
  });
}

function Table() {
  var minrows = parseInt(document.getElementById('mnrows').value);
  var maxrows = parseInt(document.getElementById('mxrows').value);
  var mincols = parseInt(document.getElementById('mncols').value);
  var maxcols = parseInt(document.getElementById('mxcols').value);
  var output = '';
  var temp = 0;
  var i = 0;
  //this checks to see that minrows are less than maxrows, if not they are switched
  if (minrows > maxrows) {
    temp = minrows;
    minrows = maxrows;
    maxrows = temp;
  }
  //this checks to see that minrows are less than maxrows, if not they are switched
  if (mincols > maxcols) {
    temp = mincols;
    mincols = maxcols;
    maxcols = temp;
  }
  temp = 0;
  var j = mincols;
  var countm = minrows;
  output = output + "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'> ";

  output = output + "<tr> <td> </td> ";

  //this part creates the column numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
  for (temp = mincols; temp <= maxcols; temp++) {
    output = output + "<td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " + temp + "</td> ";
  }
  output = output + "</tr> ";


  for (i = minrows; i <= maxrows; i++) {
    //this part creates the row numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
    output = output + "<tr> <td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " + countm + "</td> ";
    countm++;
    //this next part fills in the rows as it goes by restarting j after each while loope
    while (j <= maxcols) {
      output = output + "<td> " + i * j + "</td> ";
      j++;
    }
    output = output + "</tr> ";
    j = mincols;
  }

  output = output + "</table> ";
  document.getElementById('cooltable').innerHTML = output;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  slidez();
  val();
  sub();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Multiplication Table Creator!</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <form id="tabley-boy" name="tabley-boy" method="update">
        <div class="row">
          <label for="mnrows">Minimum for rows:</label>
          <input type="number" id="mnrows" value="0" required>
          <div id="slider_min_row"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="mxrows">Maximum for rows:</label>
          <input type="number" id="mxrows" value="10" required>
          <div id="slider_max_row"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="mncols">Minimum for columns:</label>
          <input type="number" id="mncols" value="0" required>
          <div id="slider_min_col"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="mxcols">Maximum for columns:</label>
          <input type="number" id="mxcols" value="10" required>
          <div id="slider_max_col"></div>

      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div id="cooltable">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what specifically do you need? Do you want to block user to input manually value in input boxes?

Comment: Please explain exactly what behaviour you want to implement - we can't help you fix code if we don't know what it is supposed to be doing in the first place!

Comment: I want to block user input that is put into the input boxes that is not valid

Comment: just by adding `readonly` in input fields should be OK and fine, right?
`<input readonly type="number" id="mnrows" value="0" required>`

Answer (score 0):

simple `readonly` attribute should suffice in your case, cool function by the way :)

```js
function sub() {
  if ($("form[name='tabley-boy']").valid() == true) {
    $("form[name='tabley-boy']").submit();
  }
}

function slidez() {
  $("#slider_min_row").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mnrows").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("#mnrows").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_min_row").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });

  $("#slider_max_row").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mxrows").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("#mxrows").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_max_row").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });

  $("#slider_min_col").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mncols").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("mnrows").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_min_col").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });

  $("#slider_max_col").slider({
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#mxcols").val(ui.value);
      sub();
    }
  });
  $("#mxcols").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#slider_max_col").slider("value", this.value);
    sub();
  });
}

function val() {
  $("form[name='tabley-boy']").validate({
    rules: {
      mnrows: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
        //le: '#mxrows'
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
      },
      mncols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
        //le: '#mxcols'
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 50
      }
    },
    messages: {
      mnrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
        //le: "Your minimum number for rows must be less than your maximum"
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
      },
      mncols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
        //le: "Your minimum number for columns must be less than your maximum"
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 50"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
      Table();
      return false;
    },
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
      sub();
    }
  });
}

function Table() {
  var minrows = parseInt(document.getElementById('mnrows').value);
  var maxrows = parseInt(document.getElementById('mxrows').value);
  var mincols = parseInt(document.getElementById('mncols').value);
  var maxcols = parseInt(document.getElementById('mxcols').value);
  var output = '';
  var temp = 0;
  var i = 0;
  //this checks to see that minrows are less than maxrows, if not they are switched
  if (minrows > maxrows) {
    temp = minrows;
    minrows = maxrows;
    maxrows = temp;
  }
  //this checks to see that minrows are less than maxrows, if not they are switched
  if (mincols > maxcols) {
    temp = mincols;
    mincols = maxcols;
    maxcols = temp;
  }
  temp = 0;
  var j = mincols;
  var countm = minrows;
  output = output + "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'> ";

  output = output + "<tr> <td> </td> ";

  //this part creates the column numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
  for (temp = mincols; temp <= maxcols; temp++) {
    output = output + "<td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " + temp + "</td> ";
  }
  output = output + "</tr> ";


  for (i = minrows; i <= maxrows; i++) {
    //this part creates the row numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
    output = output + "<tr> <td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " + countm + "</td> ";
    countm++;
    //this next part fills in the rows as it goes by restarting j after each while loope
    while (j <= maxcols) {
      output = output + "<td> " + i * j + "</td> ";
      j++;
    }
    output = output + "</tr> ";
    j = mincols;
  }

  output = output + "</table> ";
  document.getElementById('cooltable').innerHTML = output;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  slidez();
  val();
  sub();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Multiplication Table Creator!</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <form id="tabley-boy" name="tabley-boy" method="update">
        <div class="row">
          <label for="mnrows">Minimum for rows:</label>
          <input readonly type="number" id="mnrows" value="0" required>
          <div id="slider_min_row"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="mxrows">Maximum for rows:</label>
          <input readonly type="number" id="mxrows" value="10" required>
          <div id="slider_max_row"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="mncols">Minimum for columns:</label>
          <input readonly type="number" id="mncols" value="0" required>
          <div id="slider_min_col"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="mxcols">Maximum for columns:</label>
          <input readonly type="number" id="mxcols" value="10" required>
          <div id="slider_max_col"></div>

      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div id="cooltable">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```